# Spring - Updating multiple relationships simultaneously best practice

Tags: java, sql, spring, relationship, crud

Let's say I have an Entity `Post` which has Many `Tag`s. Users can do standard BREAD operations. (Browse, Read, Edit, Add, Delete).

My question is about the *Edit* part. when Creating (Adding) a post, the user adds some tags. The request looks like this

```json
{
  "title": "Lorem ipsum",
  "Body": "Lorem Ipsum foo bar todododo",
  ...
  "tags": [
    {
      "name": "Tag 1",
      "category": 52
    },
    {
      "name": "Tag 2",
      "category": 37
    },
    {
      "name": "Tag 3",
      "category": 52
    }
  ]
}
```

When Editing the post, the user can **delete** some tags, **edit** the tags, **add** new tags. So I'm wondering how to deal with this when saving changes.

I have 2 approaches in mind

1. Delete all old tags, then save all new tags
2. Keep track of tags IDs, update the old tags, create the new ones, delete the old tags that no longer exist after comparing old ids with new one.

Which one is the best practice?

###### Note

I'm using Spring, so with JPARepositories `rep.save(entity)` works for both *create* & *update*

###### First Approach

```java
tagRepository.deleteByPostId(postId);
for(Tag tag: request.getTags()){
  tag.setPostId(postId);
  tagRepository.save(tag);
}
```

###### SecondApproach

```java
List<Tag> tags = request.getTags();

List<Long> keepIds = tags.stream().filter(tag.getId() != null).map(tag -> tag.getId()).toList();
tagRepository.deleteByPostIdWhereIdNotIn(postId, keepIds);

for(Tag tag: tags){
  /* if tag is old tag id would be already set so entity will be updated 
   * else id would be null and new entity will be created */
  tag.setPostId(postId);
  tagRepository.save(tag);
}
```

I'm interested in the performace of each approach (if tags are few VS if tags are in hundreds). If there's a better method I'm all ears.

Thanks :)